# 1046 (1046)!No database selectedになる

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, fuelphp

fuelphpでDB(personal)のテーブル(friend)にinsertしたいのですが、
データベースが選択されていませんというエラーが出ます。
db.phpでDB(personal)を選択し、
freind2.phpでテーブルfriendを選択しているので、
No database selectedでは無いと思うのですが、
何が原因なのでしょうか。
お手数おかけしますが、ご回答頂けると幸いです。
宜しくお願いします。

エラー

```
Fuel\Core\Database_Exception [ 1046 (1046) ]:
No database selected [ INSERT INTO `friend` (`id`, `name`, `age`, `sex`) VALUES ('777', '梅宮辰夫', '71', '男') ]
```

friend2.php(/Users/■■■■/Desktop/fuelphp-1.8.1/fuel/app/classes/controller)

```
<?php

class Controller_Friend2 extends Controller  {
      //メソッド
    public function action_insert() {

    DB::insert('friend')->set(array(
        'id' => '777',
        'name' => '梅宮辰夫',
        'age' => '71',
        'sex' => '男',

    ))->execute();

         }

}

?>
```

db.php(/Users/■■■■/Desktop/fuelphp-1.8.1/fuel/app/config)

```
<?php
return array(
    'default' => array(
        'type'        => 'mysqli',
        'connection'  => array(
            'persistent' => false,
        ),
        'identifier'   => '`',
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'charset'      => 'utf8',
        'collation'    => false,
        'enable_cache' => true,
        'profiling'    => false,
        'readonly'     => false,
    ),
);
```

db.php(/Users/■■■■/Desktop/fuelphp-1.8.1/fuel/app/config/development)

```
<?php
return array(
  'default' => array(
    'connection'  => array(
        'dsn'    => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=personal',
        'port'     => '3306',
        'username'   => 'root',
        'password'   => 'root',
       ),
        'profiling' => true,
    ),
);
```

環境

```
fuelphp 1.8.1
PHP 7.1.16
```

Comment: タグの`phpmyadmin`は「PHPで書かれたMySQLの管理ツール」であり、質問に直接関係ないように見えます。ただ使っているものを列挙するのではなく、質問内容に関連するものをタグ付けするようにしてください。適切なタグ付けをすることで他のユーザが質問を参照する際の手助けとなります。

Comment: わかりました。タグ付けを気をつけます

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typeのmysqliとPDOではconnectionの書き方が違います。
PDOの場合はdsnで記述が可能ですが、mysqliの場合はdsnの記述はできず、項目ごとに変数を設定する必要があります。

mysqliの場合

```
'connection'     => array(
    'hostname'       => 'localhost',
    'port'           => '3306',
    'database'       => 'personal',
    'username'       => 'root',
    'password'       => 'root',
    'persistent'     => false,
    'compress'       => false,
),
```

マニュアルにも2種類のconnectionの書き方が紹介されています。
http://fuelphp.jp/docs/1.8/classes/database/introduction.html
詰まったらまずはマニュアルをご覧ください。